# The permutations $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ and $(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$ are conjugate in $A_n$ if and only if $n>8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am studying to a a test in Abstract Algebra and I encountered a problem I am having difficulties to solve.
The problem is:

Prove that the permutations $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ and $(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)$ are conjugate in $A_n$ if and only if $n>8$

I know that if $y^{-1}(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)y = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ then $(7y,6y,5y,4y,3y,2y,1y) = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ for $y$ is permutation in $A_n$.

But I have no idea how to go from there.
Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Proof sketch: Write $y$ as a product of disjoint cycles. For $y^{-1}(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)y = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)$ to be true, this decides what those cycles do with $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ and $7$. See what those cycles must be, and note that that part of $y$ turns out to be odd. So you need another two-element cycle to make all of $y$ even. To make room for that, you need access to $8$ and $9$.